# Django guardian user.has_perm false for existing data

Tags: django, permissions, django-guardian

I was trying to give permission using Django guardian. when I try to give permission for existing data its show me a false message but when I create a new object its show me true. what I'm doing wrong?

My code :

```
>>>from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>>from print.models import *
>>>from guardian.shortcuts import assign_perm
>>>user = User.objects.create(username='tanvir',password='antu')
>>>excel = ExcelData.objects.all()
>>>assign_perm('delete_exceldata', user, excel)
>>>user.has_perm('delete_exceldata', excel)
>>>False
```

But If I do

```
>>>from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>>from print.models import *
>>>from guardian.shortcuts import assign_perm
>>>user = User.objects.create(username='tanvir',password='antu')
>>>excel = ExcelData.objects.create(order_number='01245632145214')
>>>assign_perm('delete_exceldata', user, excel)
>>>user.has_perm('delete_exceldata', excel)
>>>True
```

Comment: excel = ExcelData.objects.all() will give you a queryset and >>>excel = ExcelData.objects.create(order_number='01245632145214') will give you an object..

Comment: Then how could I give permission for existing data in the database?

Comment: you can do it inside a loop like - for obj in excel :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
excel = ExcelData.objects.all()
```

will give you a queryset and

`excel=ExcelData.objects.create(order_number='1245632145214')`

will give you an object..

You can only assign permission to an object

if you want to assign permission for a queryset do it inside a loop

```
user = User.objects.create(username='tanvir',password='antu')
excel = ExcelData.objects.all()
for obj in excel:
    assign_perm('delete_exceldata', user, obj)
    user.has_perm('delete_exceldata', obj) # this will give you status for each obj
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how could I check permission? `user.has_perm('delete_exceldata', excel)` still return false

Comment: you can do it inside the loop just add user.has_perm('delete_exceldata', obj) it will give you status for each obj. i'll edit my code including checking perm